# copiar una tabla de una BD mysql a otra base distinta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buen día

tengo este código y necesito copiar lo que esta en la tabla **AAA** de la base de datos **localhost-base1** a la Base de datos **otroserver-base2** (están en servidores distintos), el destino (otroserver) ya tiene la tabla (**aaa**) creada dentro de **base2**, pero el localhost la **base1**, tabla **aaa** esta llena de datos y el otroservidor esta la misma tabla misma estructura pero vacía , es solo insertar los valores de la tabla (**aaa**) de localhots en otroserver (una copia)

he hecho este query pero no hace nada, no da error pero no inserta datos en otroserver:

```
<?php

$dblink1=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); // connect server 1
mysql_select_db('base1',$dblink1);  // select database 1

$dblink2=mysql_connect('otroserver', 'root', ''); // connect server 2   
mysql_select_db('base2',$dblink2); // select database 2

$table='aaa';

$tableinfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $table  ",$dblink1)); // get structure from table on server 1

mysql_query(" $tableinfo[1] ",$dblink2); // use found structure to make table on server 2

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table  ",$dblink1); // select all content     
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {       
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '",array_values($row))."')",$dblink2); // insert one row into new table
}

 mysql_close($dblink1); 
 mysql_close($dblink2);

 ?>
```

Comment: Primero de todo no muestras los errores en tu código (quiero decir que no usas mysql_last_error. Por otra parte,  las instrucciones mysql_ solo identifican la conexión con el server, user y pass. Dblink 1 y 2 son la misma conexión. Acostúmbrate a utilizar PDO o mysqli_.

Comment: Por qué no hacerlo con `phpmyadmin`?. Es tan simple como abrir la tabla y seleccionar la opción exportar, luego en el otro server usas la opción importar y eso es todo.

Comment: no lo hago con phpmyadmin por que tengo que hacer un cronjob que se ejecute cada 24 horas, voy a colocar el check errores

Comment: ademas phpmyadmin serviría para 1 servidor, estas bases están en distintos servidores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías internar haciendo `INSERT INTO tablaDestino SELECT * FROM tablaOriginal` aunque, si nada más es una única ocasión que lo vas a hacer es mejor hacer un dump
`mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 databasename > dump.sql
mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 databasename < dump.sql` la referencia original la puedes encontrar en [How to copy a table from one mysql database to another mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932608/how-to-copy-a-table-from-one-mysql-database-to-another-mysql-database)

Comment: vale si genero el archivo dump.sql 1 donde se guarda y 2 como hago para que se ejecute cada 24 horas en un cronjob?

Comment: 1. Se debería guardar en la carpeta actual [Documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) y 2. Si estás usando CRON lo puedes hacer con un Bash [Running Bash in CRONJob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239863/running-bash-inside-cronjob)

Comment: ni idea tocayo no se de linux, el cronjob lo pensaba hacer en php y ejecutarlo cada 24 horas desde el cpanel de la web o un .bat desde un servidor de windows.

Comment: se que me falta un paso en la programación pero ya he probado todo no se que mas hacer para que copie

Comment: El CRON si lo haces desde CPanel nada más es meter el comando y lo puedes meter en un Bash aunque quizá la forma que más te convenga es hacerlo con PHP y nada más ejecutar con `php script.php` desde el CRON y tú consulta que quede algo así:

Comment: `Drop table TablaDropeable;` despues pones `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TablaDropeable (SCHEMA)` y luego la llenas con `INSERT INTO TablaDropeable SELECT * FROM TablaEstatica` y como valores del CRON desde CPanel pones `month * day * week * weekday * Hour 0 minute 0` con eso se va a ejecutar todos los días a media noche

Comment: Nada más recuerdo que tú conexión debe ser independiente para cada base de datos y que debes llamar las tablas como `db1.table` y `db2.table`